# asp repeater databound

Tags: .net, asp.net, repeater, databound

I guys, isn't present databound event on asp repeater server control?

I just want to bind all my data, and at the end creates a new ItemTemplate and add it, but just when is all data binded

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use this for calculating total hours in the collection. Even though I put it into the `FooterTemplate`, you should be able to get the point.

`<asp:Repeater ID="rptRecords" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptRecords_ItemDataBound">`

```
protected void rptRecords_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
    {
        int totalHours = 0;

        foreach (RepeaterItem item in ((Repeater)sender).Items)
        {
            Label lblRowHours = (Label)item.FindControl("lblHours");
            if (lblRowHours != null)
                totalHours += Convert.ToInt32(lblRowHours.Text);
        }

        ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblHoursTotal")).Text = totalHours.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, 
is that what i need

 if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer) 

:)